# Age-sex standardization over study period

Tags: standardization, population

I have 10 years of health (number of cases of health outcome, such as asthma cases) and population data, but am using the data cross sectionally because the exposure data are also cross-sectional (due to how the exposure data were collected). The health and population data are both age, sex and geography specific.

I am calculating age- and sex-standardized rates for each geography. To calculate the age- and sex-specific rates first, I will use the sum of the cases over the study period from the health data.

My confusion is regarding the population data: should the population data also be summed, or should I take an average over the 10 years (similar to when calculating period prevalence)?

The latter seems to be more conceptually correct, but leads to standardized rates that are higher by a magnitude of 10 compared to the rates I calculate when summing the population data (i.e., 0.7 vs 0.07).

Any clarification on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to cv, enat_b! I have difficulty understanding your question and think it would be easier if you be a bit more precise: what is health data? Incidences of certain diseases or something else? What is your goal? The answer may depend on the goal - do you want to say something about average yearly incidence or total 10-year incidence? If you edit and improve your question, you will more likely get an answer :-)

Comment: I question the need for aggregating to a single cross-section *at all*. In other words, it would be much more informative to employ a panel data design to your model with cross-sections (geography) stacked up over time. This would erase the gnarly problem of how you aggregate your data to a single cross-section.